# Creating a percentage complete method for a form

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, comparative-review, form

I am a relatively new Rails developer and doctor doing research. In my Rails based research projects I often have questionnaires for which I provide a "% complete" parameter.

Here is an example.  You can see that each of the score attributes is given a value and then I can create a %. It looks awful and very un-Ruby-like. I would be keen once and for all to get an experts view and give me some steerage on how this could be cleaned up.

This method is in the `Patient` class:

```
 def percent_complete(user, patient)
   score = Score.where(user_id: user.id, patient_id: self.id).first
  if score.nil?
    return "0"
  end
  @status = 0
   score_array = [score.dx1, score.dxcon1, score.db1, score.dbcon1, score.biopsy, score.mgt]
   score_array.each do | element|
    if element == score.dx1
      @status = @status + 20
    elsif element == score.db1
      @status = @status + 20
    elsif element == score.dxcon1
      @status = @status + 20
    elsif element == score.dbcon1
      @status = @status + 20
    elsif element == score.biopsy
      @status = @status + 10
    elsif element == score.mgt
      @status = @status + 10
    end
   end
  @status
 end
```

Each `Score` belongs to a `Patient` (the `Patient` has many scores). Each `Score` belongs to a `User` (a `User` has many scores).

> score.dx1, score.dxcon1, score.db1, score.dbcon1, score.biopsy, score.mgt

These are the `Score` class attributes:

- `dx1` = diagnosis1 (string)
- `dxcon1` = diagnostic confidence1 (integer)
- `db1` = disease behaviour1 (string)
- `dbcon1` = confidence on disease behaviour (integer)
- `biopsy` = should you biopsy? (boolean)
- `mgt` = management (string)

I am now trying something like this:

```
 def percent_complete(user, patient)
    score = Score.where(user_id: user.id, patient_id: self.id).first
    if score.nil?
      return "0"
    end
    score_completeness = [score.dx1, score.dxcon1, score.db1, score.dbcon1, score.biopsy, score.mgt]
    @status = 0
    score_completeness.each do | field |
       @status += (100/6.0) unless field.blank?  
    end
   @status
 end
```

Comment: Can you fix the indentation?

Comment: Could you give us an idea of what the `Score` class looks like, and what `dx1`, `dxcon1`, … are?

Comment: But the percentage values in the second code sample don't match the original behaviour. Can you make up your mind what code you want us to review?

Comment: Many thanks for your time. The actual values are not that important. Its simply whether the method could be refactored to make it more concise. I would give an example but if I could do that, I could answer the question. I wondered is there a way to use an enumerator with the score completeness array for example to slim it down. You can see from my edit that my second attempt is less verbose. Both these methods work the way I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking only at your last block:

- Why return the string `"0"` instead of the number?
- The hard coded array is cryptic, and a potential maintenance hassle. I'd recommend moving it to a method on the `Score` model to abstract things.
- The hardcoded `100/6.0` is basically a magic number. It'd be better to get the length of whatever array you're working with than assume it's always 6.
- Why is `@status` an instance variable? Your method is meant to return something. If it returns at the first `return` line, you never even set `@status` to anything, which'll lead to errors later on, if you expect it to be set. Conversely, if you don't expect it to be set, or don't intend to use it, why set it?

I imagine you could do something like this:

```
def percent_complete(user, patient)
  score = Score.where(user_id: user.id, patient_id: self.id).first
  return 0 if score.nil? || score.steps.empty?
  100.0 * score.completed_steps.length / score.steps.length
end
```

where `Score#steps` and `Score#completed_steps` look like:

```
def steps
  [dx1, dxcon1, db1, dbcon1, biopsy, mgt]
end

def completed_steps
  steps.reject(&:blank)
end
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for - something succint that taught me some new code. Thank you. I should add that I changed the completed steps method to:                                                          steps.reject { |step| step.blank? || step.nil? } as some steps are strings and some are integers and I kept getting an error : undefined method `blank' for "":String

Comment: @GhostRider that's odd. I believe rails defines `blank?` on the Object class so it should be available on _everything_

Comment: I'll play with it for a while and see if I spoke too soon. Many thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

There are some things that are a bit unclear when it comes to the associations between `User` and `Patient`, so I'll assume that this is how everything is setup:

```
class User
  has_many :scores
  has_one :patient
end

class Score
  belongs_to :patient
  belongs_to :user
end

class Patient
  has_many :scores
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Here are some things you could improve:

- [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns): score calculation feels like it shouldn't be a `Patient` class concern. Instead it should happen at the `Score` class. Also if the calculation of score turns out to be more complex in the future, it should be extracted to a separate class for [Granularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granularity).
- [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle): each method should do one thing. The `Patient#percent_complete` is currently doing lots of stuff, it knows to much. It should request the percentage from the score and just that.
- Better naming: come up with better method names that reflect exactly what each method does. For example `#percent_complete` isn't that descriptive. What does it stand for? How can a patient be complete? This are just questions I asked myself when I saw your code.

Regarding code syntax, you could do the following:

- Don't use `self` for reading attributes. Using just the attribute works. `self` should be used when you are *writing*. Take a look [here](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#syntax) to see examples on when to use (or not) `self`.
- Since each patient `has_many :scores` you can use the `scores` method in your code and get the scores scoped to the current patient instance. Take a look at [Rails association methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) for more information on which methods become available when defining associations.
- Assuming that each patient `belongs_to` a `User`, you can use the `user_id` attribute in order to save yourself a query when requesting the score.
- Since `percent_complete` is an `Patient` instance method, why do you require patient as an argument. It's not used anywhere in the method.
- Encapsulation: do not expose methods that you don't need to be in the public interface.

You could do something like this:

```
class Patient
  has_many :scores
  belongs_to :user
end

class Score
  belongs_to :patient
  belongs_to :user

  def progress
    100 * completed_attrs_count / attrs_for_completion.count.to_f
  end

  private

  def attrs_for_completion
    %i[dx1 dxcon1 db1 dbcon1 biopsy mgt]
  end

  def completed_attrs_count
    attrs_for_completion.reject do |attr|
      public_send(attr).blank?
    end.count
  end
end

class Patient
  has_many :scores
  belongs_to :user

  def percent_complete
    score && score.progress || 0
  end

  private

  def score
    scores.where(user_id: user_id).first
  end
end
```